# Proper way of doing Geolocations using GeoIP inside a Celery task

Tags: python, django, celery, geoip

So, I have a Django middleware calling a Celery task. This task queries the GeoIP2 database to geolocate the given IP address and perform some additional processing. In the simplified form, the celery task looks like this:

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def dump_json_logs(self, data):

    g = GeoIP2()
    location = g.city(data["ip_address"])

    # some other code...
```

The thing is, this celery task may be called thousands of times a second, which will cause the `g = GeoIP2()` client to be initialized every time the task is processed. Can I move this statement outside the function so that the client is initialized only once and then passed to each task? Where should I move it to in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move it outside method scope, and use it inside method as a global variable.

```
g = GeoIP2()

@shared_task(bind=True)
def dump_json_logs(self, data):

    global g

    location = g.city(data["ip_address"])
```